# No repetir acción al presionar una tecla javascript

Tags: javascript, game

el problema que tengo es que al usar un eventListener de tipo keydown, la acción que le asigno se repite sin parar hasta que dejo de presionar la tecla.
Ejemplo:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  
    switch (e.key){
    case 'w':
    movementQuotientY+=3 
    break;
  }
}
```

Al presionar la tecla 'w', mientras esta siga presionada, se le sumará +3 a movementQuotientY hasta que deje de presionarla. Hay alguna manera de hacer que solo se ejecute la acción una vez? Es decir, que solo se le sume 3 una vez

Cosas que he probado:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  
    switch (e.key){
    case 'w':
    if(movementQuotientY < 3){
     movementQuotientY+=3
} 
    break;
  }
}
```

En un principo funciona, el problema es que 'movimentQuotient' a veces tiene valores por debajo de 0 y entonces no sirve

También he leído sobre el evento keypress pero por lo visto esta obsoleto y tampoco sirve

Comment: Usa `keyup`, o es que necesitas usar `keydown` por alguna otra razón?

Comment: Necesito usar keydown, estoy haciendo controles para mover un elemento. Necesito que la accion se realice al presionar la tecla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En caso que no necesites que la acción se repita, puedes usar la [propiedad `repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat) del evento. La misma toma el valor `true` cuando el evento es una repetición de la acción inicial, en este caso el evento es `keydown`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  switch (e.key) {
  case 'w':
    if(!e.repeat) {
      console.log("Sólo me veo una vez");
    }
    break;
  case 'r':
    console.log("Me repito");
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

En el código anterior estoy usando la propiedad `repeat` del evento cuando presiono la tecla `w`, en cambio no la uso cuando presiono la tecla `r`.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.